# How to make Reactjs not rerender certain components

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to build a full page in Reactjs but some components are persisted throughout pages. The structure is something like this:

```
<div>
  {showHeader ? header : ''}
  {showNav ? nav : ''}
  <div className="main">
    <section className="left">
      {this.props.children}
    </section>
    <section className="right>
      <section className="persist-this"/>
      {moreStuff}
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

During rerendering is the structure change is significant enough (changing from a page with header & nav to no header/no nav the `persist-this` section will be re-rendered as well.

Right now I'm actually doing `React.renderComponent` for each individual pieces & keep the structure static (so like `renderComponent` for header, nav, left section & moreStuff separately) & I wonder if there's a better way to doing this?

EDIT: I think I do know why this got re-rendered. I guess my question now becomes more like how to organize my structure better. So I got `BasePage.jsx` which has the structure above & in other pages (like `HomePage.jsx` or `OtherPage.jsx`) I do:

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <BasePage>
      <p>Home</p>
    </BasePage>
  }
});
```

I think when I do `React.renderComponent` it see `<HomePage>` & `<OtherPage>` as 2 completely different Components although they are wrapped by the same `<BasePage>`, thus unmounting the Page. Should I separate the differences of those pages into mixins?, then always `renderComponent(<BasePage>, el)` to prevent unmounting?

Comment: This might help: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/diff/

Comment: In the structure you have listed there, persist-this will not be unmounted if showHeader and showNav change or if moreStuff changes. If you're seeing it unmount, you must have something else different in your code.

Comment: It might be something on my part but I'm just curious if there's any case where React decides to re-render the whole thing instead of diff-ing subtrees & keep certain part intact?

Answer (score 1):

If something persists between pages, the correct way to do it would be to separate your structure so that whatever persists only shares an ancestor which also persists.

In other words, you should structure it like this:

```
<div id="siteRoot">
  <div className="dynamic">
    {showHeader ? header : ''}
    {showNav ? nav : ''}
    <div className="main">
      <section className="left">
        {this.props.children}
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="persist-this">
      <section className="right>
        <section/>
           {moreStuff}
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your css should adapt to your new dom hierarchy and update your layout accordingly.

Now when you switch content in your dynamic section, React will automatically know that it doesn't need to re-render anything in the persist section - since nothing was changed there.